# Sql UPDATE query append X to end of column

Tags: sql

I have a table called Blog, which has a List property called Posts. Posts is of type Post, which is also another table.

I want to write a SQL update query that prepends every blog's Name with 'X' if they have at least one post that was before 21/march/2015

```
UPDATE tblblog
    SET tblblog.Name = CONCAT (tblblog.Name, 'X')
WHERE tblblog.post.time < Convert(datetime, ''21/03/2015")
```

I am new to sql is this the best approach

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product specific functionality used there.

Comment: please post what RDBMS and version are you using

Comment: prepend means before, append means after, your query is appending but your question says prepend... which pend do you want?

Comment: You have single quotes at the beginning and a double quote at the end of your date.

Comment: change this part `Convert(datetime, ''21/03/2015")` with `Convert(datetime, '21/03/2015', 103)`

Comment: Do you really have a field called "post.time"?  Most databases will read that as part of a schema owner name (MSSQL) or schema (MySQL).  Dates generally are 2015-03-21 BTW.

Comment: @SQLDBA `post.time` is indeed a peculiar column name, might need to be enclosed with double qoutes. The order of month and day in date serialiations however depends heavily on the locale, in Germany day comes first, then month and year (though you would commonly use '.' as separator instead of '/'). @codespider Is your snippet production code or paper-and-pencil design ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL server use below query :

```
UPDATE tblblog SET tblblog.Name = tblblog.Name + 'X'
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,tblblog.post.time,'2015-03-21') <= 0
```

f you use MySQL use below query :

```
UPDATE tblblog SET tblblog.Name =  CONCAT(tblblog.Name,'X')
WHERE DATE(tblblog.post.time) < '2015-03-21'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the following as a template. The precise syntax depends on the actual rdbms that you are using. This suggestion does not address possible performance issues

```
UPDATE tblblog t
   SET t.Name = CONCAT ('X', t.Name)
 WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
             FROM tblblog st
            WHERE st.Name = t.Name
              AND st.post.time < Convert(datetime, '21/03/2015')
       );
```